# Python scrolledtext module

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I want to create a ScrolledText widget using scrolledtext module for creating a GUI in python . I have successfully created a ScrolledText widget , however i am not able to add a horizontal scroll bar to it .

```
e3=ScrolledText(window3,width=24,height=13)
e3.grid(row=5,column=1,rowspan=6,columnspan=4)
```

The above code snippet is used to create the ScrolledText widget .

[ScrolledText Widget Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8gHMy.jpg)

The widget contains only vertical scrollbar . I want to add a horizontal scrollbar to it as well . Any idea how to do it ?

UPDATE: The ScrolledText widget is being used to accept a multiline input . Check the picture attached.

[ScrolledText widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewOVz.jpg)

Comment: Why use the scrolled text widget? It's trivial to add both horizontal and vertical scrollbars to a text widget with just a couple lines of code. Are you open to solutions that don't use `ScrolledText`?

Comment: @BryanOakley . Actually I am creating a email sender app for which i need a multiline entry widget . Tha'ts why i'm using ScrolledText .Also the reason i need a horizontal scroller is to enable the user to document his email identation properly . I'll attach a screenshot of the entire screen . And , yes i am fine with alternative solutions .

Comment: Instead of ScrolledText , if there is any other widget that allows multiline input with both horizontal and vertical scrollbar options , I can use it .
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewOVz.jpg

Comment: Yes, you can use the `Text` widget.

Comment: Can you provide a code example with the scrollbar config as well ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can implement a scrolled text widget yourself with a text widget and a couple of scrollbars.

Here's an example that puts a text widget and two scrollbars in a frame, so that they appear as if they are a single widget. This is pretty much exactly what the `ScrolledText` widget does:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

textContainer = tk.Frame(root, borderwidth=1, relief="sunken")
text = tk.Text(textContainer, width=24, height=13, wrap="none", borderwidth=0)
textVsb = tk.Scrollbar(textContainer, orient="vertical", command=text.yview)
textHsb = tk.Scrollbar(textContainer, orient="horizontal", command=text.xview)
text.configure(yscrollcommand=textVsb.set, xscrollcommand=textHsb.set)

text.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
textVsb.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="ns")
textHsb.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="ew")

textContainer.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
textContainer.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

textContainer.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

root.mainloop()
```